# Why is the order taken into account in this probability problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

There is this example in my statistics/probability book (The Birthday Problem). The problem is to find the probability that at least two people have the same birthday in a group of 100 people. To simplify the problem, they disregard leap years and assume a uniform distribution of birthdays over the 365 days of the year.

To assign birthdays to 100 people, they choose 100 out of 365 with replacement and get $365^{100}$ different combinations. This is what confuses me a bit. When I first saw $365^{100}$ it seemed to make sense. But if you take $365^{100}$, you take the order of all the birthdays into regard, right? Why would you need to take the order into regard in this problem? The thing that matters is only WHICH birthdays, not the order of them? Doesn't that make more sense? I would be thankful for some guidance!

Comment: You have only provided half the argument.  It's fine to imagine that the people are ordered...just put them in a line.  The point is to be consistent.  $365^{100}$ could well be the denominator, but then the numerator would also have to respect the order.

Comment: To stress: working with unordered collections is harder work here, as your collections are not equiprobable.   Working with ordered collections removes this difficulty.

Comment: @Lulu thanks! I understand!